# Django Admin site does not Load the css and images

Tags: python, css, django, path, admin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1OnS.png)

This is urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('todolist.urls')),
    path('', include('account.urls')),
]
```

his is setting.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR / 'static'),

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')        
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

This sis all file...Can Any One Please help me on my issue ???
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

you have configured below one in your your project/urls.py file?

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response.... its file in my local machine. but when i deploy in live server then not work...;(

Comment: from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.registration_view, name='register'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)